# Problems with running Ubuntu os

Tags: system-installation

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my notebook. I chose **alongside with Windows 7** mode. The installation was successful. After restarting and rejecting the Ubuntu disk computer started to load Windows without asking me make a choice between Ubuntu and Windows? What's a problem guys? Moreover I checked Ubuntu disk again it showed me that Ubuntu has already been installed and ready to use.

Comment: try boot-repair.

Comment: For Recovering Ubuntu visit Ubuntu-Help https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows and for boot repair: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 2):

You need to install GRUB (GRand Unified Boot-loader).

The installer should have asked if you want to install GRUB and you should have said YES.
I think you can choose OS at boot time by pressing F8 or F12.

You should install a boot-loader either from Ubuntu (if you manage to start it) or directly from Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend installing EasyBCD and add an entry for Ubuntu in bootloader.

Search Google for how to use EasyBCD to know more.